# Center logo in Boostrap Wordpress menu on resizing

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, alignment, navbar

So, by default Bootstrap show logo on left corner, but on resizing it is still on the left. I want to put it in the middle to make it nicer display.

Image of what i have:
[What i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hlj5R.png)

Image of what i want to be displayed:
[What i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82wCT.png)

I have this code to display Bootstrap menu in Wordpress:

```
<header>
  <div class="menu">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
      <div class="container" id="menu2">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
              <img alt="Logo" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/img/logo.png">
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="navbar-collapse collapse col-md-9" id="menu1">
            <?php wp_nav_menu(array(
                'theme_location' => 'primary',
                'container' => false,
                'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right'));
              ?>

          </div>

        </nav>
      </div>
</header>
```

I tried text-align:center, but it only works for links, not for logo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ok, i solved the problem by adding this:**

```
    @media (min-width:768px) {
  .navbar .navbar-nav {
      display: inline-block;
      float: none;
  }

  .navbar-brand{
    display: inline-block;
    float: none !important;
  }

  .navbar .navbar-collapse {
      text-align: center;
      margin: 0 auto;
  }

  .navbar-nav > li {
      display: inline-block;
      float:none;
  }
}

@media(max-width:1200px) {
.navbar-header {
        text-align: center;
        margin: 10px;
        float: none !important;
    }
  }
```

Now the brand logo is centered when there is no space and links go down.

**I also created clean Bootstrap navbar example without Wordpress for another users who want to see how it works** *(run and display it on full screen and resize window to see effect)*:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <style>
      @media (min-width:768px) {
    .navbar .navbar-nav {
      display: inline-block;
      float: none;
    }

    .navbar-brand{
    display: inline-block;
    float: none !important;
    }

    .navbar .navbar-collapse {
      text-align: center;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .navbar-nav > li {
      display: inline-block;
      float:none;
    }
    }

    @media(max-width:1200px) {
    .navbar-header {
        text-align: center;
        margin: 10px;
        float: none !important;
    }
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite a different layout for your header with logo in the center and make use of bootstrap helper classes making visible the appropriate header. for your reference. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Another approach is to play with offsets
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting